# magento2.2.3 site is blank after di compie

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile

Can anyone help me how to resolve the below problem.

after di:compile command my site is blank in windows xampp server.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Worked for me after remove **global.php** file under magento root **/genereted/metadata/**

Thanks

Comment: Hi, but what is the global.php file for?

Comment: By removing global.php, magento falls back to developer mode, even if the mode is production. This is why it works. The problem is that the system will not run in production mode, but does in developer mode.

Comment: After that u need to enable production mode via command

Answer (score 1):

aftre di compile use this command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
rm -rf var/generation var/cache var/page_cache var/view_preprocessed
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: i was running windows 10 and i used to see blank screen after di:compile. I tried on ubuntu 16.04 LTS and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Please go to **app\bootstrap.php**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

and also check log files under **var/log** or **var/repor**t folders

or else you can first do these,

First delete below folders : go to root directory

```
pub\static

var\cache

var\page_cache

var\view_preprocessed

var\generation
```

And run below commands

**php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**

**php bin/magento indexer:reindex**

Answer (score 1):

This can be caused by any error. Please enable the error reporting by editing your bootstrap.php file located at following path:

***magento_root/app/bootstrap.php***

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Check the deployment mode and switch it to developer to get more information about the error.
Check the logs and reports found at following path:

***magento_root/var/log***

***magento_root/var/report***

If the issue persist, try clearing following directories:

***magento_root/pub/static***

***magento_root/var/cache***

***magento_root/var/page_cache***

***magento_root/var/view_preprocessed***

***magento_root/generated***

And run following commands from console:

> ***php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f***
>
> ***php bin/magento indexer:reindex***
>
> ***php bin/magento cache:flush***

Answer (score 1):

```
 1. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
 2. php bin/magento indexer:reindex
 3. php bin/magento cache:flush
```

and did not got my home page after trying all the above , then i tried one more command

```
- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
 - php bin/magento cache:flush
```

and then I can see my home page.